# Passing props from parent to child returns undefined in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React and I am building a simple app to experiment with props. I have an input field that searches the database based on the user input and I want to display the results in a different component that loads after the search and is a child to the Search component. When I pass the data from the Search component to the SearchResultsPage Component I get that `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` and I don't know why, how can I pass the data properly via props?
Here is my Search component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Spinner from '../../components/Spinner/Spinner.jsx';
import SearchResultsPage from '../SearchResultsPage/SearchResultsPage.jsx';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from "axios";

class Search extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            searchResults: [],
            isLoading: false,
            isSearchStringFound: true
        }
    }


    getSearchQuery = (event) => {
        const SEARCH_RESULTS_ENDPOINT = process.env.REACT_APP_SEARCH_ENDPOINT;

        const searchString = document.querySelector(".search-input").value;

        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            this.setState({ ...this.state, isLoading: true });
            axios.post(SEARCH_RESULTS_ENDPOINT, {
                searchString: searchString,

            }).then(response => {
                this.setState({ ...this.state, searchResults: response.data });

                if (response.data.length === 0) {
                    this.setState({ ...this.state, isSearchStringFound: false });
                }

                else if (response.data.length > 0) {
                    this.setState({ ...this.state, isSearchStringFound: true });
                }

                this.setState({ ...this.state, isLoading: false });
                window.location.href = "/blog/searchResults"
            });
        }
    };

    render() {
        if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return <Spinner />
        }
        return (

            <div>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Search"
                    className="search-input"
                    onKeyDown={(e) => this.getSearchQuery(e)}

                />
                <div>
                    <SearchResultsPage
                        searchResults={this.state.searchResults}
                        isSearchStringFound={this.state.isSearchStringFound}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Search;
```

and my ResultsPage component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import Footer from '../Footer/Footer.jsx';
import CustomHeader from '../CustomHeader/CustomHeader.jsx';
let title = 'Blog'

class SearchResultsPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <CustomHeader
                    title={title}
                />
                <div>
                    {this.props.isSearchStringFound === false ? <div className="no-results-found">No results were found</div> : this.props.searchResults.map(result => (
                        <div key={result._id} >
                            <img src={result.picture} alt="avatar" />
                            <div >
                                <div>
                                    <h2>{result.title}</h2>
                                    <p>{result.date}</p>
                                    <p>{result.postContent}</p>
                                    <Link to={`/post/${result._id}`} className="read-more-btn">
                                        <button className="read-more-btn">Read more</button>
                                    </Link>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        )
    }
};



export default SearchResultsPage;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't updating the state correctly. State updates inside event handlers are batched and are asynchronous which is why the state isn't correctly updated causing the error in child component

Also spreading `this.state` with `this.setState` isn't needed and you shouldn't be needed to redirect after axios call as the component is already rendered

You can update your state with a single setState invocation like

```
 axios.post(SEARCH_RESULTS_ENDPOINT, {
            searchString: searchString,

        }).then(response => {
            const data = response.data;
            let isSearchStringFound;

            if (response.data.length === 0) {
                isSearchStringFound= false;
            }

            else if (response.data.length > 0) {
                isSearchStringFound = true;
            }

            this.setState({ isSearchStringFound, searchResults: data, isLoading: false });
        });
```

Comment: Did you make sure you are updating state once and like `this.setState({ isSearchStringFound, searchResults: data, isLoading: false });` IF so did you log and see what does response.data return from axios request

Comment: Yes I did it like that

Comment: Do you receive the error on initial render or on calling getSearchQuery. Alsoare you getting any errors in console apart from cannot read property map of undefined

Comment: I receive it after I type a letter and hit enter

Comment: can you log, `console.log(data, isSearchStringFound);` before `this.setState({ isSearchStringFound, searchResults: data, isLoading: false });` and share the result

Comment: Yes, with a match I get this: ```Array(NumberOfMatchedDocuments) true``` without a match I get   ```Array(0) false``` before being redirected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215098/discussion-between-shubham-khatri-and-mahma-deva).